# Tamanho da pagina ecrãs diferentes HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

A minha duvida é em criar uma pagina em html e css e essa mesma página ser aberta em ecrãs diferentes.

Por exemplo agora surgiu-me um pequeno problema.

HTML:

```
<iframe id="contentframe" width="300px" height="350px"  src="demo_iframe.htm" name="iframe_a"></iframe>
```

CSS:

```
#contentframe{
position: absolute;
left: 76.5%;
top: 130px;
}
```

Se abrir numa pagina num ecrã grande a margem é maior do que num ecrã pequeno. 
Como consigo corrigir isso? 
Quero que apareça sempre a mesma margem independentemente do ecrã que abra a página.

Answer (score 1):

Usa isto para controlar a largura e altura e demais propriedades:

```
iframe, object, embed {
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
}
```